# linearlayout programmatically causes error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I have an existing fragment in xml format as below

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/phoneLinearLyout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/title_mar_gap"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/title_mar_gap"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CL"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|left|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Contact No"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CNV"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/callButton"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:background="@color/Blue"
                        android:text="Call" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Now I have activity class where in oncreateview I have below code -

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_above_fragmentView, container, false);

LinearLayuot llayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phoneLinearLyout);
```

And I am trying to TextView in linearlayout Fragment_above_fragmentView (as mentioned in the first XML posted) dynamically with following code .

```
for (int i=0;i<2(variable here);i++)
    {


        contactDisplay = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contanctNumberValue);
        contactDisplay.setTypeface(typeface);


        contactDisplay.setText(dataModel.getTelNo());
        //contactDisplay.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          llayout.addView(contactDisplay);
        //phoneLinearLyout.updateViewLayout(contactDisplay,);
    }
```

But, facing an error as Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first and application gets crashed.

Comment: `contactDisplay` is already added to the `LinearLayout`. Why are you trying to add it again?

Comment: actually I need to have multiple textview to get added in already existing linearlayout , I could have taken array of textviews but even adding contactDisplay one time is not working (for i=0;i<1;i++) ...

Comment: "but even adding contactDisplay one time is not working" - Yes, because it's already added. That's why you're able to find it with `findViewById()`. Finding a `View`, and trying to add it again, doesn't make it a new, different `View`. You have to create new ones, either by direct instantiation, or inflating a layout with your `View` defined in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new `TextView` and add into llayout.

```js
for (int i=0;i<2(variable here);i++)
{
   TextView contactDisplay = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   contactDisplay.setTypeface(typeface);
   contactDisplay.setText(dataModel.getTelNo());
   llayout.addView(contactDisplay);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I am very beginner programmer in Android .I came to know that once one id is used then we can't use the same id in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to removeAllViews before adding view to layout :

```
llayout.removeAllViews(); //add this

for (int i=0;i<2(variable here);i++)
    {


        contactDisplay = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contanctNumberValue);
        contactDisplay.setTypeface(typeface);


        contactDisplay.setText(dataModel.getTelNo());
        //contactDisplay.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          llayout.addView(contactDisplay);
        //phoneLinearLyout.updateViewLayout(contactDisplay,);

    }
```

Comment: Already tried but application had crashed., tried now again at the place pointed out by you but app crashed without specific error in log.

Answer (score 0):

for (int i=0;i<2(variable here);i++)
    {

```
    contactDisplay = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contanctNumberValue);
    contactDisplay.setTypeface(typeface);
```

if(contactDisplay.getParent()!=null)
    ((ViewGroup)tv.getParent()).removeView(contactDisplay);

```
    contactDisplay.setText(dataModel.getTelNo());
    //contactDisplay.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      llayout.addView(contactDisplay);
    //phoneLinearLyout.updateViewLayout(contactDisplay,);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created textview each time rather than pointing to the same one which is already used.